# Angular2 rxjs multiple result

Tags: angular, rxjs

First, I'm sorry I do not have enough English.

Hi, I make something with angular2.

This is part of my code.

```
  public computePredictedGameRate( targetGame: Game, targetUser: User, compareUsers: User[]):number {
    var observableCompareUsers = Observable.from(compareUsers);
    var result = -123;

    Observable.forkJoin(
      this.gameRateService.getGameRatesById( targetUser.id ),
      observableCompareUsers.flatMap( compareUser => this.gameRateService.getGameRatesById( compareUser.id ) ),
      observableCompareUsers.flatMap( compareUser => this.gameRateService.getGameRateByTitleAndId( targetGame.title, compareUser.id ) )
    ).subscribe(
      res => {
        //something for result;
      }
    );
    return result;
  }
```

I want to get values of them.

```
this.gameRateService.getGameRatesById( compareUser.id )
this.gameRateService.getGameRateByTitleAndId( targetGame.title, compareUser.id )
```

compareUsers have 5 users.

So, The functions return value[5][?]

but, I can't get their whole value.
they return just last one. like value[?] <= this value is fifth user own.

i think they emit value one by one and overwrite themselves.

please help me. I have sleep just 3 hours for 2 days.

Comment: I am sorry that I have to reply late. My country is at 3 am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Observable.forkJoin` works like this:

```js
Observable.forkJoin(
   obs1,
   obs2,
   obs3
).subscribe(result => {
   const resultOfObs1 = result[0];
   const resultOfObs2 = result[1];
   const resultOfObs3 = result[2];
});
```

You can `map` the forked-result and return a new Observable..

```js
public computePredictedGameRate(
   targetGame: Game,
   targetUser: User,
   compareUsers: User[]
): Observable<number> { // <<-- return's an Observable instead a number .. !

    var observableCompareUsers = Observable.from(compareUsers);

    return Observable.forkJoin(
       this.gameRateService.getGameRatesById( targetUser.id ),
       observableCompareUsers.flatMap( compareUser => this.gameRateService.getGameRatesById( compareUser.id ) ),
       observableCompareUsers.flatMap( compareUser => this.gameRateService.getGameRateByTitleAndId( targetGame.title, compareUser.id ) )
    ).map(res => {
       const gameRatesById1 = res[0];
       const gameRatesById2 = res[1];
       const gameRatesByTitle = res[2];

       // do something with the results..
       // ..    

       return -123; // your numeric return value here !
   });
}
```

And then call it like this:

```js
computePredictedGameRate(game, user, users).subscribe(gameRate => {
   console.log(gameRate);
});
```

Comment: I want to have game rating information for 5 users. But now you can only get information about just one.
Even if i use the method you gave me, I can only get information about one person.
compareUsers is a list of 5 users and I want to get game rating information for each compareUser.

Comment: Or is there another way I can do it? Since I am using rxjs for the first time, I do not know how other functions are used.

Comment: I am asleep and get up and check the next answer. I'm sorry.